How is the quantum harmonic oscillator related to Fock states?
The question is basically in the title.
From what I understand, in the Fock state there is a certain number of particles in each energy level. The creation/annihilation operators create or destroy a particle in the respective energy level.
The quantum harmonic oscillator is rather the energy of a single particle, and the creation/annihilation operators do not destroy the particle but give or remove a quantized energy unit. That is why they are usually called the ladder operators.
Is this reasoning true? And how one could connect both concepts?
Also, what is the role of the number operator in a quantum harmonic oscillator? It does not seem to represent the number of particles if by definition the quantum harmonic oscillator is for a single particle.

The Fock space $F(\mathfrak h)$ constructed from the single-particle Hilbert space $\mathfrak h\cong \mathbb C$ is $F(\mathfrak h)\cong \ell^2$. From this, you can view the QHO as a single particle with infinitely many single-particle states or as one single-particle state with possibly infinitely many number of particles, roughly speaking. I saw this reasoning in some books here and there.

You are asking about field quantization: the arrangement of an infinity of  the normal modes of a quantum field as distinct (commuting) SHOs of characteristic frequencies. In this language, the energy of each mode is the number of "particles" or excitations at that frequency.

It is an analogy. People used the notion of a quantum harmonic oscillator (QHO) to develop the formalism with which we model quantum physics. In this development the action of a ladder operator that changes the state of the QHO is used to model quantum interactions or processes in which particle are transformed. Strictly speaking, one does not need the QHO to develop such a formalism. It follows simply by casting Fourier theory in terms of an operator formalism, leading to the same commutation relations for ladder operators.
